# Render image does not change despite changes in nodes

Tags: rendering, texturing

I´m doing an blenderguru tutorial to learn how to texture, and, despite I´m doing exactly what he says and using  the same textures, my renders keep on looking wrong. In the images I attach I show the nodes and you can see in a white square the map for metalic section (he uses that map also). But, as you see, the render keeps on showing the texture wrong (black part should be metalic gray and white stains should be rusty metal. No matter if I put that metalic map or invert it (mostly black),the render image always looks like that one. Any idea? (render mode is set in cycles).

Thanks a lot[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWkqv.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

What you see in your viewport seem correct, considering your node tree.

However, there's something that does not look correct in your node tree, that being the maths multiply node between your color texture and your principled shader. Remove that, and it should have a more logical result.

Answer (score 0):

.He put this multiply node in order to lighten a bit the figure.  I made what yoy said: removed the multiply node, and it still looks wrong (it´s only change are the stains, wich look deddish now, not white). 
thanks a lof for answering